# Having two tables - one for selecting, one for updating

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which gets constantly updated with a lot of real-time data. In order to make it scalable, it would be best if it doesn't have any indexes to make updates as fast as possible. When I fetch the data, I group it by days, so the selects don't need to be real-time, but it would be great if they were indexed:

Table structure:

```
id | date | fk_1 | fk_2 | some_data | incr
```

Update SQL:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(null, DATE(NOW()), 5, 2, 'some data', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY SET incr = incr + 1;
```

Is it a good practice to make a duplicated table with proper indexes each day, and use it for selects, while keeping the original table unindexed and used for updates? (the table has few million rows).

Comment: Did you run performance tests on a single indexed table? What will be the load (writes per second)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is good practice to have different databases for gathering "operational" data and for running queries.  However, replicating the data from one system to another imposes an additional load, so it might not directly solve your problem.

Before doing that, though, you should test other solutions.  First, what is your update load?  A single index on date does impose overhead but it doesn't cause the database to grind to a halt.  On reasonable hardware the database should still be able to manage hundreds of modifications per second.

If you only care about one column and you mean *filtering* by days, then partitioning the data by date might be a good solution.

Third, as for performance, I might be more concerned about the `select` queries interfering with the DML queries than with the overhead of indexes.  This is where a second database for querying is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more information about your "updates"? Are they only updating a certain range of dates and are your selects only targeting a few dates? If so, look into filtered indexes, those might be useful to serve queries that target everything except for today (if your updates are targeting only today).